# Spanish phrase similar to "lay my cards on the table"

Tags: traducción, modismos, español-neutral, inglés

Is there a similar expression to express that one is being honest and forthright, and not hiding information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the phrase you're looking for is

'Poner las cartas sobre la mesa', a quite literal translation.

Comment: Depending on localization, "cartas" might be interchanged with "naipes"

Comment: In Spanish from Spain, this expression is correct and well known.

Comment: The question is which one is the translation ;-).

Comment: @spanish-guest-9834798345 donde se usa _naipes_?

Answer (score 7):

Otra opción, con el mismo significado, es **mostrar las cartas**. Se trata de una frase hecha, que deriva directamente de **mostrar**:

> **Mostrar**. 1. tr. Manifestar o poner a la vista algo, o enseñarlo o señalarlo para que se vea.

Answer (score 5):

DLE [says](https://dle.rae.es/carta#LCps30h):

> **poner [...] las cartas boca arriba**
>
> 1. loc.verb. Poner de manifiesto un propósito u opinión que se guardaba oculto.

DLE also mentions **enseñar las cartas** as a synonym. So both **poner las cartas boca arriba** and **enseñar las cartas** have that meaning of "showing your intentions or opinions, which were previously hidden".

I have always said **poner las cartas sobre la mesa**, though. I do not think it is uncommon to say it that way.

Comment: Living in Colombia and Spain, in both countries I have always heard "poner las cartas sobre la mesa" and "enseñar las cartas". Both sound natural to me, more than "poner las cartas boca arriba"

Answer (score 3):

I add these two expressions that mean something similar (at least in Chile):

> Hablar *a calzón quitado*.

> Hablar *sin pelos en la lengua*.

These expressions mean to say things with total frankness, without hiding anything. They differ from "*poner las cartas sobre la mesa*" in that they also express shamelessness, speaking without censorship or social or moral concealment.

Answer (score 0):

At least related is the equivalent to the English *to come clean:* One decides to *stop* hiding something (and, if you want, lay all cards on the table). The Spanish translation is simply *confesar [algo]*, to confess something.

(In German one could also say "die Hosen runterlassen", literally "let down your pants", to reveal what was previously concealed, in an embarrassing fashion, often under pressure. But I think this idiom has no direct equivalent in Spanish.)